# "Внутренняя" таблица стилей

Tags: jquery, style, php, html, css

Есть веб-страница основного сайта. Для краткости буду называть ее главной.
На этой странице между тегами `<div></div>` на php иклудится другая страница совершенно другого сайта оформленного по всем правилам верстки (`<html><head></head><body></body></html>`). У каждой из этих страниц свои абсолютно разные таблицы стилей. Как сделать так, чтобы стили с побочной страницы не пересекались со стилями главной страницы?
Например, вот простой стиль главной страницы:

```
body {color: black}
```

А вот стиль побочной страницы:

```
body {color: white}
```

При это необходимо, чтобы ко всем элементам побочной страницы можно было также применить jQuery с основной страницы, чтобы, например, получить html код элемента h1 побочной страницы:

```
alert($('#div_v_kotorom_lejit_pobochnaya_stranica > h1').html());
alert($('#div_v_kotorom_lejit_pobochnaya_stranica').find('h1').html());
alert($('h1','#div_v_kotorom_lejit_pobochnaya_stranica').html());
```

Вообщем, нужно иметь доступ ко всем элементам побочной страницы, также как я имею доступ к элементам главной страницы, поэтому вариант c iframe, как я понимаю, не подходит...

Основная задача: не допустить перемешивание стилей двух разных страниц.
Есть идея во всех стилях **побочной** страницы преписывать перед каждой строкой этот самый айдишник div'а. Т.е. писать:

```
#div_v_kotorom_lejit_pobochnaya_stranica body {color: white}
```

Но это слишком муторно. А для автоматической "приписки" и парсинга каждого стиля маловато ресурсов, которые и так стараешься экономить.
Поэтому хотелось узнать, может кто сталкивался с подобной или такой же проблемой, и знает решение по-адекватнее?

Comment: Стиль вложенной страницы надо сохранить? + обращение вида "`
<pre>var ifr = document.getElementById('myIframe').contentDocument;

ifr.document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = 'lol';</pre>
`" вам знакомо?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет. Знакомо не было. И за это огромное вам спасибо. ) Решил проблему, обращаясь к элементу по принципу:

```
alert($('iframe').contents().find('h1').html());
```